# Regex function to validate ' MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm' in python

Tags: python

I have used the regex function

```
**r'\d{4}-\d?\d-\d?\d (?:2[0-3]|[01]?[0-9]):[0-5]?[0-9]:[0-5]?[0-9]'**
```

but it doesn't work on the date data in the format : 01/02/2020 05:25 AM

Where am I going wrong

Comment: Why do you expect `MM/DD/YYYY` to work when your regex expects `YYYY-MM-DD`?

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex is trying to match YYYY-MM-DD for the date. And it is also expecting a 24-hour time of the format HH:MM:SS when your data only has hours and minutes and uses AM/PM (and so, hours will run from 01 to 12 not 00 to 23).

This regex will do what you want: \d?\d/\d?\d/\d{4} [0-1][0-9]:[0-5][0-9] ([AP]M)

But you should not use a regex for this, because the validation it performs will be short of the mark. This regex will match 31 February as if it were correct, and it isn't.

Use `datetime.datetime.strptime()` instead, with format `%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p`.

```
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime("01/02/2020 05:25 AM", "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p")
datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 2, 5, 25)
```

This is better because `strptime()` knows about months with less than 31 days, and leap years.

```
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime("02/29/2020 05:25 AM", "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p")
datetime.datetime(2020, 2, 29, 5, 25)
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime("02/29/2021 05:25 AM", "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "E:\Python27\lib\_strptime.py", line 458, in _strptime
    datetime_date(year, 1, 1).toordinal() + 1
ValueError: day is out of range for month
```

This shows you that you need to put a `try...except ValueError` block around your `strptime()` call to trap invalid dates.

And, besides validation, why else should you convert your string to a datetime? Well, because the next thing you will want to do is store the date in a variable for processing, or in a database for storage. You're *not* planning to store it as a string, are you?

Comment: I'm trying to split data based on date and time from a long text. I used the regex  function \d?\d/\d?\d/\d{4} [0-1][0-9]:[0-5][0-9] and it does help me to split data but the date just vanishes from the split data. I want to retain date and time also. can it be done

Comment: For that you need to show us the code that deleting the data. If you are successfully splitting the data then the regex is doing what you want. It's the code that isn't. Edit your question to include it.

Comment: Thank you !! It was great help :)